# How to call a parent method from kendo template binding?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, kendo-mvvm

I have the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9fLS/12/). I'm trying to call the parent method lowestMpgMsg for each of the elements inside the array cars. I have try using the following bindings with no luck:

```
data-bind="text: lowestMpgMsg()"
data-bind="text: parent.lowestMpgMsg()"
data-bind="text: parent().lowestMpgMsg()"
data-bind="text: parent().lowestMpgMsg"
```

Thank you!

Here is my html

```
<div class="container">
<div id="template-container" data-template="template" data-bind="source: cars"></div>
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div>
        <span data-bind="text: brand"></span> - 
        <span data-bind="text: mpg"></span> - 
        <span data-bind="text: lowestMpgMsg()"></span> - 
    </div>
</script>
```

and here is my javascript

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    cars: [
        {brand: "Toyota", mpg: 22},
        {brand: "Mini", mpg: 32},
        {brand: "Honda", mpg: 23}
    ],
    lowestMpgMsg: function(e) {
        var sorted = this.cars.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.mpg - b.mpg > 0;
        });

        return e.mpg > sorted[0].mpg ? "no" : "yes";
    }
});

kendo.bind($("#template-container"), viewModel);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that you don't have to--it calls the parent method on the parent automatically, reminiscent of how the prototype chain works. The longer answer is the correct syntax isn't one listed in your question AND the code has a subtle error with the way you're using `this`.

First, notice that [bindings are not javascript](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/mvvm/overview#important). The MVVM overview in the documentation clarifies that you cannot invoke methods in bindings, so nothing with parenthesis is going to be legal syntax. Even if you could, you would have to call the parent method twice from a car instance:

```
var car = viewModel.cars[0];
var cars = car.parent();
var model = car.parent().parent();
var lowestFn = model.lowestMpgMsg.bind(model); //the bind makes this refer to the intended object
```

This means you would need something to bind to something like `parent().parent().lowestMpgMsg()`

The good news is that `data-bind="text: lowestMpgMsg"` will behave like you want it to. It will call the item's `parent().parent().lowestMpgMsg()`. To see the basic parent chain working,  changing the template to

```
    <script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <div>
            <span data-bind="text: brand"></span> - 
            <span data-bind="text: mpg"></span> - 
            <span data-bind="text: lowestMpgMsg"></span> - 
        </div>
    </script>
```

and the model to

```
    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        cars: [
            {brand: "Toyota", mpg: 22},
            {brand: "Mini", mpg: 32},
            {brand: "Honda", mpg: 23}
        ],
        lowestMpgMsg: function(e) {       
            return Math.random();
        }
    });
```

Now, let's get to why your `lowestMpgMsg` isn't working. Start by noticing that the method throws an exception on your viewmodel, but not in the object that is wrapped:

```
viewModel.lowestMpgMsg({mpg:15}); //throws exception

var notWrapped = {
    cars: [
        {brand: "Toyota", mpg: 22},
        {brand: "Mini", mpg: 32},
        {brand: "Honda", mpg: 23}
    ],
    lowestMpgMsg: function(e) {
        var sorted = this.cars.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.mpg - b.mpg > 0;
        });
        return e.mpg > sorted[0].mpg ? "no" : "yes";
    }
}
notWrapped.lowestMpgMsg({mpg:15}); //no exception
```

When the `lowestMpgMsg` is invoked during binding, the `this.cars` refers to the same object as `viewModel.cars` and is an `instanceof` type `kendo.data.ObservableArray`, which does not have a `sort` method.

Finally, be sure to [use a get method for the calculated field](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/mvvm/observableobject#important), so the MVVM framework knows to update it when dependencies change.